# exception in Buffered Reader

Tags: java, exception, bufferedreader, string

I am trying to read from console using bufferedreader in a very simple code

```
System.out.println("Enter a port number : ");

    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = bufferRead.readLine();
        int port = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

When the message is printed, it doesn't give me any time to write in the console and it goes straight to showing a Java.lang.NumberFormat Exception  as in I didn't enter anything.
Any suggestion to what might be wrong?

Comment: Did u try to debug the code?

Comment: no, because this small code is very easy and I used it a lot of times but I don't know what is happening so that it doesn't give me time to right anything down. I used Scanner and it gives the same result

Comment: @rima101 are you pressing `enter` key before entering any values?

Comment: ^^That does not seem to be a good reason to not debug it

Comment: `BufferedReader` reads without being asked to, he does that to buffer the data. So maybe he reads some end-of-line, end-of-file, etc char -  which is not a number,  that causes the exception.

Comment: ...Could it be that your keyboard is broken?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Console.readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to read input from the console. You can get an instance of `Console` using [`System.console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29).

Example:

```
String s = System.console().readLine("Enter a port number: ");
int port = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

If `System.console()` returns null, that means that (from the JVM's perspective) you don't actually have a console. This may happen if your standard input has been redirected.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = bufferRead.readLine();

if(input != null && !input.isEmpty()) {
    int port = Integer.parseInt(input);
} else {
    // Handle end of stream
}
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) for *readLine* method.

You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). You can do-

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
```

**UPDATE:**

Based from you comments, here's the entire class-

```
import java.io.*;

public class SOTest1{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Enter a port number : ");

        BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String input = bufferRead.readLine();

        if(isNumber(input)){
            int port = Integer.parseInt(input);
            System.out.println("entered port :: " + port);    
        } else {
            System.out.println("entered port is not a number :: " + input);
        }            

    }

    public static boolean isNumber(final String str) {

       if(str == null || str.isEmpty()){
           return false;
       }

        int size = str.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by handle end of stream

Comment: @rima101 If you checked the reference link I gave, you would have seen under readLine method - this method returns "A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached."

Comment: @rima101 If you run the program and press enter, you need to check if the string is empty too.

Comment: I tried both of them and nothing changed. It simply doesn't give me the time to write anything

Comment: @rima101 Check the update. Copy the class SOTest1 and place it in a file named SOTest1.java. Then compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why are you facing this issue. I executed your code from within Eclipse IDE and from a windows command prompt and both seem to work fine.
So, as a standalone code it works fine but if you are facing the issue intermittently then it could be due to the reason that some unread characters are already there in the input stream hence not allowing you to enter further data needed for `read()` method.
As a cleanup i would recommend to call

```
System.in.skip(System.in.available());
```

before calling `read()`.

Comment: Same here. Had no problems.

Comment: After you run, just press enter without any input.

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly fine. But I added some checks and some try-catch blocks.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Enter a port number: ");

    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = null;
    Integer i = null;
    try
    {
      s = bufferRead.readLine();
      System.out.println("INPUT: " + s);

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    if (s == null)
      return;

    try
    {
      i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
      return;
    }
    System.out.println("PORT: " + i);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you running this code ?
I tried it on eclipse and it worked fine for me

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter a port number : ");

    BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s = bufferRead.readLine();
        int port = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println("entered port :: " + port);    
}
```

Here is the output

```
Enter a port number : 
56
entered port :: 56
```

Comment: After you run, just press enter without any input.

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  System.out.println("Enter a port number : ");

  BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String s = bufferRead.readLine();
  try {
   int port = Integer.parseInt(s);
   System.out.println("entered port :: " + port);
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
   System.out.println("handle your exception scenario here");
  }
 }

Comment: Using try..catch  to validate input is a bad idea. You can just check- if(s != null && !s.isEmpty())

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it in Eclipse, check your run config. On the tab common, there is the section Standard Input and Output. Check that "Allocate console (necessary for input)" is checked.